# How to use let* Monad syntax for Lists

Tags: ocaml

I'm playing around with OCaml's let* syntax but I can't get anything to work when working with Lists.
When I try to define a (not very useful) dupe function like this:

```
let (let*) = List.concat_map

let dupe xs = let* f = (fun a -> [a;a]) xs in f
```

It fails to compile with error:

```
The operator let* has type ('a -> 'b list) -> 'a list -> 'b list
       but it was expected to have type ('a -> 'b list) -> ('c -> 'd) -> 'e
       Type 'a list is not compatible with type 'c -> 'd
```

I don't understand why the compiler seems to think my xs variable is of type ('c -> 'd). Explicitly defining the type as in (xs: 'a list) in the method definition doesn't help.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concat_map` function has type `('a -> 'b list) -> 'a list -> 'b list`, in other words it expects the map function first contrarily to the `bind` function.
In other words, the arguments order need to be reversed to define `(let*)`:

```ml
let (let*) m body = List.concat_map body m
let dupe xs = let* f = [xs;xs] in f
```

Comment: Note: `let (let*) = Fun.flip List.concat_map` might be tempting, but the value restriction strikes back, resulting in `'_weak1 list -> ('_weak1 -> '_weak2 list) -> '_weak2 list` rather than `'a list -> ('a -> 'b list) -> 'b list`.